# Bootstrap Container Width Instead of Screen Width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4, but I don't want to use screen width. I want layout over whatever width the container has.

I couldn't find the details after searching.

The following codes are placed according to the screen width. However, I want it to be adjusted according to the current width of the container I specified.

```html
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-4">

SIDEBAR

</div>

<div class="col-lg-8">

<div class="row"> /*The following boxes should be shaped according to the width of this container.*/
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3">A</div>
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3">B</div>
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3">C</div>
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3">D</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure what you need exactly, but it seems that you want a boxed layout instead a fluid one. If you use a `.container` class will apply the boxed effect you want.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-4">Column</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-4">Column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the documentation:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

If this is not what you need, please try to be more clear about your goal.

Comment: Boxes take 3 or 4 widths depending on the screen width.

However, I want to set the boxes by calculating how wide the container div is.

In other words, although I use col-lg-2 col-md-4 and the width of the container is 900px, the layout moves according to the screen width.

As it stands, it continues to use col-lg-2. But he should have used col-md.

I hope I was able to explain.

Comment: Could you possibly send an screenshot or something to illustrates your goal? Because I'm not able to understand what you want to achieve. Sorry.

Comment: It's actually very simple. You have 2 boxes col-lg-2 col-md-4.

The container div is 900px wide. However, col-lg-2 is used because it is processed according to the media query value. Because the screen width is 1280px.

What I want to do is to choose lg, md, sm etc. according to the container width.

Comment: I think I understand. Bootstrap mediaqueries works with screen width or ratio. You can't set a mediaquery to observe a DOM element. It is more simple if you just build your own classes to change when you need it, but even this way mediaqueries behavior won't change and you must play by its rules.

Comment: @riga so basically you want "container queries" - only those are not actually a thing yet, they are only in the early stages of the specification process, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries

Comment: This is the biggest contraint of Bootstrap it relies on css media queries based on the client width for when it breaks to another layout and not whatever you decide to call your container. So the moment you e.g. add a button bar or side elements your actual container would be smaller width but the breakpoints still dependent on client width. Also does not play well with transform scale to make thing bigger as that doesnt make the client width smaller either, hence Bootstrap breakpoints are ignored.